# Apache serving when 000-default.conf is disabled

Tags: apache-2.4, defaults

Apache is still serving from 000-default even after I removed from site-enabled using
a2dissite 000-default.conf

My apache version is 2.4.7 and I am running ubuntu. Apache is still behaving the same way as I have configured previously.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any virtual hosts defined/configured, Apache will still serve the requests using its default virtual host. It's default document root in most linux systems is /var/www/html/

You can check these settings inside /etc/apache2/apache2.conf on ubuntu systems